# js parse json multiple elements vs single

Tags: javascript, json

I have some client data that sometines returns a json array and sometimes a single result.

tried:

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);
if(Array.isArray(data)){
    console.log ("is array");
    //loop
    ..
    //end loop
 } else {
    console.log ("isn't array");
    //process
 }
```

But haven't got it working. Even a single json result is being detected as array.

In js, how do I work with it properly?

---

json looks like:

```
 {"item":{"clave":"CEL-37","codigo_fabricante":"A2554181"}}
```

and

```
{"item":[{"clave":"AC-2972","codigo_fabricante":"EBP-2-003"},{"clave":"SWS-1994","codigo_fabricante":"TMBD-044"}]}
```

Comment: you have if(Array.isArray(data)) intead of if(Array.isArray(json))

Comment: What do you mean by single result? It is still array if enclosed in `[]`. You can check length of array and if it equals 1, then you're good to go :)

Comment: @contrabit thanks for the suggestion. If I use if(Array.isArray(json))  my result goes on sayng both of them are not an array.

Comment: If those two examples are actually what you consider having an object and an array, I can tell you that both of those are not arrays. Probably you are considering the value of the `item` property. If you want this to distinguish is that array or not, and you are always sure that you will have this `item` property, you can test `if(Array.isArray(json.item))`

Comment: Thank you contrabit, you're right. It is indeed the item property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the json data you provided, are json object, simply because it's enclosed in brackets `{}`. You have to check for `item`, not the whole object

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);
if(Array.isArray(json.item)){
    console.log ("is array");
    //loop
    ..
    //end loop
 } else {
    console.log ("isn't array");
    //process
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, tried the solution and for some reason (data.item) won't work (returns nan) in second case. Used (json.item) and works as expected. Best regards.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it. Obviously, It won't work because `data` is a string